# For-loop list comprehension with strip() function

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, strip, python-3.8

This is my file:

```
test1,30 (# assuming \n is here)
test2,undefined (# assuming \n is here)
test3,5 valid attempts
```

This is my current code:

```
## <> arrows suggests input & not shown here

import os

os.system(<file path directory>)
with open(<file path directory>) as openDocument:
    openfile = openDocument.read()
    openfile = openfile .replace("\x00", "").split("\n")   
    openfile = [openfile .split(",") for openfile in openfile [1:]]
    openFinalFile = {policyName.strip(): policyValue.strip() for policyName, policyValue in openFile if policyName != ''} ## Currently causing an error

    print(openFinalFile["test1"])
```

How do I make it such that if I do print(openFinalFile["test1"]), it'll return the value which is 30 (shown in file)?

Error returned: builtins.ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: In your code you have a comment `## Currently causing an error`. Can you edit the question and put the error there?

Comment: `openFinalFile` is not defined yet when you use: `for policyName, policyValue in openFinalFile`. What are you expecting to happen there?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. For debugging questions, you need to provide a [mre], but you haven't provided the error message. As well, I think you're confused about something, cause directories aren't executable, and can't be opened like a file (at least not on Linux - not sure about other OS's). Even if "directory" was a typo, it still doesn't make much sense. So you need to provide complete code - nothing in angle brackets. Also see [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: I've updated the code & put the error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather user `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
lines = Path(<file path directory>).read_text().replace("\x00", "").splitlines()
pairs = [i.split(',') for i in lines]
openFinalFile = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in pairs if k}
print(openFinalFile["test1"])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and get back to you soon :)